# "ImportError: No module named tkinter" when using Pmw

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, importerror

Here's my problem: I'm running the code in [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/271249-how-to-create-linked-optionmenus-or-other-lists-in/) example.  I have Python 2.7 and 3 installed on my RaspberryPi but I have checked and double-checked, and I am running the code in 2.7.  I've installed Pmw 2.0.0 under 2.7, not 3, but when I try to run, I get the "ImportError: No module named tkinter" error.  I use Tkinter all the time, so it usually works fine, and I've done a search to verify that I'm definitely calling "Tkinter", not "tkinter", so I think it has to be a problem with Pmw, which also seems to be indicated by the traceback (posted in full at the bottom of my question).  I can't for the life of me find a specific place where Pmw is looking for lower-case "tkinter", and I'm at a loss for how to work around this.  I'm not eager to switch platforms--this is for work, so unless this is unfixable, I need to stick with Tkinter.  Oh, and I am pretty new to Python, so I would love to find out that it's a simple problem that someone on here can spot easily.

import sys; print sys.path gives me:

```
['/home/pi/Desktop', '/home/pi', '/usr/bin', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7']
```

The full traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/LinkedMenusSample.py", line 151, in <module>
    Pmw.initialise(root)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Pmw/Pmw_2_0_0/lib/PmwLoader.py", line 131, in __getattr__
    self._initialise()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Pmw/Pmw_2_0_0/lib/PmwLoader.py", line 89, in _initialise
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: No module named tkinter
```

Comment: What distribution is this?

Comment: The Raspian version of Debian that's linked on RaspberryPi site.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Maybe I can help you on how to remove the error.

here are two thoughts:

1) you use python 2.xx and have installed the python 3 pwm module (Tkinter was renamed to tkinter from Python 2 to 3)

2) you do the following before the import and hope it helps:

```
#import tkinter
#Traceback (most recent call last):
#  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
#    import tkinter
#ImportError: No module named tkinter

import sys, Tkinter
sys.modules['tkinter'] = Tkinter # put the module where python looks first for modules
#import tkinter # now works!
```

Comment: Thank you!  This solved my problem.  I'd previously tried importing Tkinter as tkinter and all kinds of things like that, but I hadn't tried assigning it like this.
EDIT: I'd upvote you, but I guess I don't have enough rep.  Sorry about that.

Comment: If you can not import `Tkinter` in Python 2.x then you have got a different error/problem. The module is exactly written like `Tkinter` in Python 2.x.

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround would be the following:

```
try:
    import tkinter
except:
    import Tkinter as tkinter
```

This way you would always have the module tkinter available and depending on the Python version your program loads tkinter or Tkinter.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem with `matplotlib.pyplot` (python 2.7+) in my CentOs. I solved the problem by just installing the tkinter. `sudo yum install tkinter`. Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

you have imported wrong module use:
import Tkinter

Answer (score -1):

## rewritten script that runs on python 3.4.0 onwards

```
def add():
        print ("Enter the two numbers to Add")
        A=int(input("Enter A: "))
        B=int(input("Enter B: "))
        return A + B 

def sub():
        print ("Enter the two numbers to Subtract")
        A=int(input("Enter A: "))
        B=int(input("Enter B: "))
        return A - B

def mul():
        print ("Enter the two numbers to Multiply")
        A=int(input("Enter A: "))
        B=int(input("Enter B: "))
        return A * B

def div():
        print ("Enter the two number to Divide")
        A=float(input("Enter A: "))
        B=float(input("Enter B: "))
        return A / B

print ("1: ADDITION")
print ("2: SUBTRACTION")
print ("3: MULTIPLICATION")
print ("4: DIVISION")
print ("0: QUIT")

while True:

    CHOICE = int(input("ENTER THE CORRESPONDING NUMBER FOR CALCULATION ")) 

    if CHOICE == 1: 
        print ('ADDING TWO NUMBERS:')
        print (add())

    elif CHOICE == 2:
        print ('SUBTRACTING TWO NUMBERS')
        print (sub())

    elif CHOICE == 3:
        print ('MULTIPLYING TWO NUMBERS')
        print (mul())

    elif CHOICE == 4:
        print ("DIVIDEING TWO NUMBERS")
        print (div())

    elif CHOICE == 0:
        exit()
    else:
        print ("The value Enter value from 1-4")
```