# Trouble connecting Eclipse, tkinter, Swampy and TurtleWorld

Tags: python, eclipse, python-2.7, swampy

I am trying to perform Think Python's turtle-related programs in Eclipse but I always seem to have one error bugging me.

It seems like I have installed Eclipse, Python 2.6 and Python 3.3 correctly in my computer, and linked them to Eclipse via Window>>Preferences>>Interpreter - Python >> New Folder in Libraries. I also did this with Swampy215 and 216.

**I run with no problems:**

```
import tkinter
import swampy
from swampy import *
```

**BUT, when I run:**
import swampy.TurtleWorld
OR
from swampy import TurtleWorld
I get these error messages:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        import swampy.TurtleWorld   File "C:\Users\mellofr\Downloads\swampy-2.1.6\swampy\TurtleWorld.py", line 8, in <module>
        from Tkinter import TOP, BOTTOM, LEFT, RIGHT, END, LAST, NONE, SUNKEN 
     ImportError: No module named 'Tkinter'
```

Weirdly, when I type import swampy. Eclipse suggests "TurtleWorld", but seems to ask for Tkinter (Python 2.7) in this process.

Comment: I find that in python 2.7, if you want to use tkinter module, you import it by typing `import Tkinter` or `from Tkinter import ...`

Try doing: `from swampy import swampy` and see what happens with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does changing the first line to

```
import tkinter as Tkinter
```

help?

See also:
["ImportError: No module named tkinter" when using Pmw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14587980/importerror-no-module-named-tkinter-when-using-pmw)